# getting csrf tokens for json post requests to a rails app

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, csrf, rest-client

I have been playing around with using rest-client to access a rails app I have written. I've written a quick script to log in and make a post request. Everything is working but I did have to work round the fact that no authenticity_token is served if you make a request for a form in json. I had to make a regular html request in other get the authenticity_token and then included this in the json I submitted as part of my post request. Basically I have a quick an dirty script like the one below

```
private_resource = RestClient::Resource.new( 'https://mysite.com')

params =  {:user => {:email => 'user@mysite.com', :password => 'please'}}
#log in
login_response = private_resource['users/sign_in'].post(params, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
#get cookie
cookie = login_response.cookies
#get json  
json_response = private_resource['products/new'].get(:content_type => :json, :accept => :json, :cookies => cookie)
#another request that returns html form with authenticity token 
response_with_token = private_resource['products/new'].get( :cookies => cookie)
#extract token 
token = Nokogiri::XML(response_with_token).css('input[name=authenticity_token]').first.attr('value')
#update cookie
cookie = response_with_token.cookies
#populate form and insert token
form = JSON.parse(json_response)
form['name'] = "my product"
form['authenticity_token'] = token
#submit the request
private_resource['products'].post(form.to_json, {:cookies => cookie, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json})
```

There is the option to turn off CSRF protection for json requests but I would rather not do that. I could go the mechanize route or something similar and then I wouldn't worry about json requests with  CSRF but I just wanted to play around with doing this stuff with rest-client

I guess I'm just curious to know if there is a reason why no authenticity_token is served for json requests and I'm also wondering if there is a better way of solving the token problem than the pretty hacky approach I've taken here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the below code into your application controller :

```
def verified_request?
    if request.content_type == "application/json"
      true
    else
      super()
    end
end
```

And call this method using before_filter .

For more details check :
http://blog.technopathllc.com/2011/09/rails-31-csrf-token-authenticity-for.html

And check this issue in rails : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3041

Comment: Thanks for your reply swati, it looks useful. I guess though I was trying to avoid just turning off the CSRF checks. It just seems a little strange to me that rails serves json forms that don't contain any token but then checks for a token. Would it make sense just to serve the json forms with a token included rather than switching off the checks for json content?

Comment: welcome ... yes that's only way to by-pass the CSRF token issue . If you want to pass token with your JSON request, you can use header like : headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
  }

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503447/rails-how-to-add-csrf-protection-to-forms-created-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

In your `app/views/products/new.json.jbuilder`, add this:

```
json.authenticity_token form_authenticity_token
```

This will insert a key `"authenticity_token"` with value being the token, so in your `json_response` you get the token as well. Idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762902).