# session become nil in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In our Rails 4.2 app, a method `view_handler` in module's application controller is getting `nil` with `session` variables. Here is the code structure:

```
class my_module < ApplicationController
  def view_handler
    #access session[:page_step] which is defined in controller.
  end
end
```

Default cookie store is used for the session:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session'
```

We verified that this is not a `scope` issue because the problem remains the same when `view_handler` is moved into main app's `application controller`.

In debug with `application controller`, the `session` object exists but with `nil` value:

```
>session.present? #false
>session.nil? #true
>session[:page_step] #nil
```

Here is the `session` object in debug. @delegate which holds app defined session variables is empty:

[image]

Also in debug, the `session[:page_step]` re-surfaces again late in `controller` action. Somehow the `session[:page_step]` (and other session variables) becomes `nil` in `application controller` and re-surface in `controller`. Since by default `session variables` in `application controller` are available in `RAILS`, what could cause them becoming nil in `application controller`?

Comment: Perhaps [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30791578/1544012) is related?

Comment: In our case there are quite a few session variables created and stored in the `session`. It is not the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps a CSRF issue: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576525/1483788 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you are experiencing a [CSRF Issue](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

> If the security token doesn't match what was expected, the session will be reset

To check if it is a CSRF issue, you can temporarily disable the `protect_from_forgery` line in your ApplicationController

Additionally, make sure your configuration for [Session Storage](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) is complete with secret keys in `config/secrets.yml` for non-production environments and as an environment variable for your production.

Secret keys can be generated with as follows in a console:

```
$ rake secret
82d58d3dfb91238b495a311eb8539edf5064784f1d58994679db8363ec241c745bef0b446bfe44d66cbf91a2f4e497d8f6b1ef1656e3f405b0d263a9617ac75e
```

Each time a new secret key is used, older sessions using other keys will not validate and the result of the session will be nil.

**Comments directly from generated file `config/secrets.yml` (Rails 4.2):**

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rake secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.
```

Comment: Removed `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in Rails application, restart server and the session problem remains. There are secret_key_bases for development, test and production. What else could cause reset session?

Comment: Have you tried all major browsers in order to replicate this issue? Clean installs (w/ no extensions or add-ons) work best.

Comment: Both firefox and IE has the same problem. The code has been used for a long time and not sure what caused the problem.