# Passing a param[:commit] value when calling form.submit() via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

When I create multiple buttons for the same form in Rails, I can use the value of param[:commit] to figure out which button was pushed.

[How do I create multiple submit buttons for the same form in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027149/how-do-i-create-multiple-submit-buttons-for-the-same-form-in-rails)

However, I have a search results page where a user can further refine the search, updating the results by selecting or deselecting facets, changing date filters, etc.  I'd like to be able to trigger a form.submit() using javascript when a facet checkbox is checked/unchecked, for example.  How do I pass a parameter (such as the param[:commit] mechanism) to my controller so that I know which user action triggered the refresh.  I don't want to make everything a button.

```
$('.facet').on('change', function(e) {

    // Do some stuff

    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.submit();  // I want to pass in a "facet-selected" here so I know what triggered the submit

});
```

With a controller method that looks like this

```
def refresh_search
    if params[:commit] == 'facet-selected'
        # Do something
    elsif params[:commit] == 'date-range-changed'
        # Do something else
    end
end
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Christy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should change form a bit, add hidden input same name as submit buttons and set it value when submit form by JS. E.g.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="commit" />    
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="date-range-changed" />    
</form>
```

Script

```
var $form = $(this).closest('form');
$form.find(':hidden').val('facet-selected');
$form.submit();
```