# Two submit buttons but only one remote:true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an form with two submit buttons so that i can perform tasks like this:

```
<% form_for(something) do |f| %>
  ..
  <%= f.submit 'A' %>
  <%= f.submit 'B' %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def <controller action>
  if params[:commit] == 'A'
      # A was pressed 
  elsif params[:commit] == 'B'
      # B was pressed
  end
end
```

So my question is how can i say that when the form gets submitted with button 'A' the form is:

```
<% form_for(something), :remote => true do |f| %>
```

And when its gets sumitted with button B its an normal form:

```
<% form_for(something) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do it this way, I think. But, it can be done via javascript.

Remove the remote true form your form. Add a javascript callback to one of your submit buttons click events to submit the form via ajax. Adjust your controller accordingly.

Comment: Yes Thanks! The problem is that i hav no really practice in ajax via javascript!

Comment: Its a common solution so a quick google will yield you a good result.