# How to create useless buttons in rails form_for

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, button, form-for

I know that if you just type something like `<button>Something</button>` outside a form_for in rails, it will create a useless button.
But I want to create buttons within this form_for to be handled by JavaScript.
Is there a way to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create useless buttons that can be handled by JavaScript.

Plain HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert('Hello.')" value="Click Here" />
```

Rails:

```
<%= submit_tag "Click Here", :type => 'button', :onclick => 'alert("Hello.")' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for Rails to use it, why not just use the plain html inside the form_for?

```
<%= form_for @record do |f| %>

  ## inputs ##

  <button>Something</button>
  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [How do I create multiple submit buttons for the same form in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027149/how-do-i-create-multiple-submit-buttons-for-the-same-form-in-rails)

```
<% form_for(something) do |f| %>
    ..
    <%= f.submit 'A' %>
    <%= f.submit 'B' %>
    ..
<% end %>
```