# Rails ajax post from button that sends values from outside of the form in the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm somewhat new to rails and am wrapping a GUI around a CLI tool to give some non-technical users some self-service. Part of the tool contains a page where the user selects a few values from some drop downs etc, and then clicks one of a few buttons on the screen to kick off their desired actions. The fields where they make their selections are outside of the forms that the buttons belong to. On button click, I want to call a javascript function that will grab the values the user selected, and post an ajax call back to the server to run the command corresponding to the button, and then when the request returns I want to insert the command output into a text area.

The only problem I'm having is with getting the values of the fields outside of the form generated by button to, and including them in the ajax request. Outside of rails this is pretty trivial, but I'm having a hard time getting this to work. Does anybody have any suggestions or examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no need for what I was trying to do... it ends up I can just use the form_tag helper and multiple submit_tag helpers to create the submit buttons with different values. See this post for details: [How do I create multiple submit buttons for the same form in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027149/how-do-i-create-multiple-submit-buttons-for-the-same-form-in-rails)

Also, here is a great write up on the javascript portion (it uses coffee script, but I didn't have any trouble following it even though I'm using jquery): http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html