# Create Simple Rails Filter for a Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newest version of Rails.

I have a table Positions that contains several columns, but the one in question is 'status'.  This is a string based column that holds values 'Add' 'Error' 'Drop'.  I have the table rendering in a view and wish to create links that will filter the data returned in the table, limited by status.

```
Add | Error

ID | Name | Status
1    Bob    Add
2    Jim    Error
```

If I clicked the Add link above the table in the view it will change the data in the table to only show Bob, since he has a status of Add.  If I clicked Error link it will only display Jim.

I can currently limit the view data with
`@positions = Position.where(:status => "Add")` but I want to invoke this limit upon link click.

Thanks for the help and if I need to define further please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add link_to links that pass their respective status as params, then adjust that controller action and return @positions based on params[:status] if it is present.

Link

```
link_to "Error", positions_path(:status => "Error")
```

Controller

```
if params[:status].present? 
  @positions = Position.where(status: params[:status])
else
  @positions = Position.all
end
```

Comment: I'm on board with the controller adjustments.  Can you provide me an example of the link_to setting the status?

Comment: Thank you so much.  The syntax on the link_to was causing me trouble, but your example cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly as described here in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027233/1023609

Create a form with 2 submit buttons or more. In your action you use the submitted value from the params hash to make your query and change the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, you can do something like:

```
link_to "Add", your_path(status: "Add")
link_to "Error", your_path(status: "Error")
```

Where `your_path` is the path to the controller/action you are doing the filter. In that controller do the following:

```
@positions = Position.where(:status => params[:status])
```