# Reformat a form_tag to form_for to use formaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `form_tag` in my `edit` view:

```
<%= form_tag stage_batch_path(@stage_batch), multipart: true, class: 'form-inline', role: 'form', method: :put do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'csv_batch_file', 'Select batch file' %>
    <%= file_field_tag 'csv_batch_file', class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'potential_item_id', 'Input item id' %>
    <%= text_field_tag "potential_item_id" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <%= button_tag 'Stage', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Currently it `put`s to `stage_batches/:id` which is what I want.

However, I want to add another button that `post`s to some other controller, say `Foo#create`. I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536941/2909897) that the `formaction` option will work. But the given example uses `form_for` and not `form_tag`:

```
<% form_for(something) do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    <%= f.submit "Special Action", formaction: special_action_path %>
<% end %>
```

How do I rewrite my `form_tag` as a `form_for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag stage_batch_path(@stage_batch), multipart: true, class: 'form-inline', role: 'form', method: :put do %>
```

==>

```
<%= form_for @stage_batch, url: stage_batch_path(@stage_batch), multipart: true, class: 'form-inline', role: 'form', method: :put do |f|%>
```

Also the same as:

```
<%= form_for @stage_batch, class: 'form-inline' do |f|%> #if @stage_batch is new_record? then method: :post, else method: :put
```

PS: You should try this https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form, a lifesaver.

With simple_form your form can be transformed to:

```
<%= simple_form_for @stage_batch do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :csv_batch_file, as: :file %>
  <%= f.input :potential_item_id %>
  <%= f.submit 'stage' %>
<%end%>
```

simple and beautiful.

Comment: Can you add an example using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and submitting a `PUT` and `POST` to different routes from the same form?

Comment: But how do I submit the form to one of two different routes? Say `Foo#create` or `Bar#edit`?

Comment: Form generated by form_for & simple_form_for follows  RESTful rule , which means it submit object.new to [object_path(object), method: :post] and object.edit to [object_path(object), method: :put].